# How do I access more specific location with getReference?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have a FireBase DB like this:

DB name

|

school

- 1

  ㄴName:blahblah

  ㄴInfo:blahblah
- 2

  ㄴName:blahblah

  ㄴInfo:blahblah

and I'm trying to access Name and Info value inside 1 or 2 using getReference, but I can only access to school DB and get value 1 and 2. Please Help!

```
myRef = database.getReference(school);

//How do I get to deeper locations
```

Comment: how do you get your value 1 and 2? by using addValueEventListener?

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Beside that, what do you want to get 1 **OR** 2 or you want to get 1 **AND** 2? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add it before onCreate().

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference childRef = myRef.child("1").child("name");
```